# File Upload with data-ajax=false PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have following Form definition on PHP page:

```
<FORM action="formSave.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">

<!-- Some HTML controls here -->

<input type="file" name="foto" id="foto"  />

</FORM>
```

`formSave.php`:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if($key=="foto")
    {
        echo "Photo attached: ".$_FILES["foto"]["name"];
    }
}
```

But it does not print file name.

How can I use file upload in addition to `data-ajax="false"`.

Please note that I am using `data-ajax=false` for the first time in my life. I heard that it is used to enable/disable ajax call for mobile devices.

Comment: files are accessible thru `$_FILES`.

Comment: There is no key `foto` at `$_POST`. Files are stored in a separate array - `$_FILES`, there and only there. You'll have to work with both `$_POST` and `$_FILES`.

Comment: can you explain little more with code?

Comment: Don't know what to explain) Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - the most popular function to work with uploaded files.

Comment: In a **See Also** block there's a link to a little manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file uploading, you should use `$_FILES` super-global variable:

```
<?php print_r($_FILES['foto']); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<FORM action="formSave.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">

<!-- Some HTML controls here -->

<input type="file" name="foto" id="foto"  />

</FORM>
```

formSave.php

```
$filename = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
```